# Stoner-Wohlfarth hysteresis at 0 magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields, material-science, ferromagnetism

There is something that is confusing me about the Stoner-Wohlfarth model. Looking at the wiki page, one sees this picture for the hysteresis loop:
[image]

The angles denoted are the angles between the field and the easy axis. Notice how the larger $\theta$ is, the smaller $m_h$ is at $h=0$. But now here is the condition for the energy to be at a minimum (which can also be found in the wiki article):
$$ \frac{1}{2}\sin(2(\phi-\theta))+h \sin \phi=0$$
When the field is zero, the only solution of that is when $\theta=\phi$. This is the case where $m$ is parallel to the field, so everything being normalized, for any angle $\theta$, $m_h$ should be 1! What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my error. I got confused because of two different conventions I encountered. In the convention of the wiki article, $\phi$ is the angle the magnetic field makes with $H$, therefore it is $\cos(\phi)$ that gives $m_h$, not $\cos(\phi-\theta)$.